# What is the runtime complexity of determining the host for a given hash slot?

Tags: redis

I am interested in setting up a Redis cluster. For reasons I won't get into, I would like the cluster to many small, non-contiguous ranges. If I have a cluster with three masters, then the cluster should look like this:

```
host1 master 0-2,3-5,6-8,...,1002-1004
host2 master 1005-7,...,2004-2006
host3 master 2007-2009,...,etc.
```

I am wondering if there is any runtime impact of setting up a cluster like this, or is it ok?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After taking a cursory look at the code, it appears that there shouldn't be an impact. The data structures used to manage the slot mapping in the cluster are fixed so the number of ranges shouldn't matter in terms of space/time complexity.